# How to open cmd and execute command using bat file?

Tags: batch-file

As i am new to JAVA programming, I used to compile and run classes using Command Prompt. But I am lazy to open and set paths every time in CMD. I found that can set the folder's path automatically using a batch file by placing it in the folder that i want to specify. **But I dont know how to set the path of the jdk bin folder using bat file.**

I just typed `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin` but no hope.

So please can you guys tell me what is the code for do that. Thank you.

Comment: Your `set` command line is valid only in the `cmd` instance it is running; maybe `setx` could do the trick (type `setx /?`); however, this is not native to Windows XP, and I do not know how about Windows Vista...

Comment: Sorry but It didnt work. But i found the solution.

Comment: path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin";%path%

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 
(1) You want to set path to JDK bin AND (2) the path must be available even after the batch file terminates.

In such a case, please consider setting it this way:
https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

> Windows 8
>
> 1. Drag the Mouse pointer to the Right bottom corner of the screen
> 2. Click on the Search icon and type: Control Panel
> 3. Click on -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
> 4. Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
> 5. In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
> 6. Close the window.
> 7. Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

> Windows 7
>
> 1. Select Computer from the Start menu
> 2. Choose System Properties from the context menu
> 3. Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
> 4. Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
> 5. In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
> 6. Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

> Windows XP
>
> 1. Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
> 2. Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
> 3. In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
> 4. Close the window.
> 5. Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

> Windows Vista
>
> 1. Right click My Computer icon
> 2. Choose Properties from the context menu
> 3. Click Advanced tab (Advanced system settings link in Vista)
> 4. In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
> 5. Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

UPDATE: Quoted from website, as per suggestion by @Brian Tompsett